# html form - upload file to storage without php

Tags: javascript, html, file

All the exmaple I saw was with a form that redirect to file upload.php. I want to do a little differnt.

I have a form and there I have :

```
<input type="file" name="img1"  id="img1">
```

and in the end of the form:

```
<button type="button" class="submit-button" onclick="signUp()"/> signup </button>
```

I want in the signUp() function to store the file in my storage and get url to thiss file.

What I did so far is :

```
 var fileUploadControl = $("#img1")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {

  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];

......................

}
```

but I don't know how to continue. thanks!

Comment: what you mean with storage? localStorage?

Comment: no , regular storage..

Comment: i mean to get url to static url (now i have the user local url..)

Comment: like Phonix answered .. you need a serverside script to save the file on the server ike php.at the other side you can't save files without the users permission with javascript.but then even if he saves the file you don't have access to that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to store data/file without using a server side language(like PHP,C#,...).
Else anyone could save files to your server and that is something you don't want!

Answer (score 1):

I recommenced to use a combination of HTML and PHP! You will find a good documentation on http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php